# TeamCity, .net build with paket / incompatible agent

Tags: teamcity, paket

How do I get TC to fetch paket dependencies?

I've just installed TC and created a CI build to build my VS 2015 .Net solution.

I checked in an empty solution, added TC Build step (Build - Visual Studio sln) and it builds. So far, so good.

Then added a project using paket and checked it in.
Added a Command Line step in TC that calls paket restore.

I am however told that TC can't build as the agent is not compatible.

How do I make it compatible/ use paket in a way the TC can handle?

BR, Anders

Comment: Specific problem resolved -- I added two steps; 1) paket.bootstrapper.exe and 2) paket.exe restore.